# SAS: reset template for crosstabs to default (proc template)

Tags: templates, sas, proc

I recently used a proc template on SAS to make some results stand out, but it seems I accidentally overwrote the default settings to display crosstabs from proc freq, as all my crosstabs are now displayed with my defined format.

I basically did a proc template thinking it was like a non-permanent procedure (I used a piece of code from the internet).

`proc template; define crosstabs Base.Freq.CrossTabFreqs; cell_style={foreground=color. fontweight=bold background=light grey};end; run;`

If I use `ods path sashelp.tmplmst(read);`, my crosstabs go back to normal but if I don't run this code, the "template version" is used for my crosstabs.

Current ODS PATH list is:

1. SASUSER.TEMPLAT(UPDATE)
2. SASHELP.TMPLMST(READ)

What should I do?

Comment: What is your default setting for ODS PATH? You need to find the updated version and delete it or move it to some other place.  So search the paths in order until you find it.

Comment: @tom How do I search the ods paths?

Comment: You can use `ODS path show;` to see your current path.  I think SAS made a BAD decision when they decided to make the shipped default be `SASUSER.TEMPLATE(UPDATE)` first in the search.  Many people don't realize they are accumulating permanent templates.  Some clients may have a different default.  I typically use `ods path work.templat(update) sashelp.tmplmst(read);`

Comment: So my current ODS PATH list is: 

1. SASUSER.TEMPLAT(UPDATE) 
2. SASHELP.TMPLMST(READ)

Comment: That means your templates are being written to the SASUSER directory.  To see what that directory is, submit: `%put %sysfunc(pathname(sasuser)) ;`    you should see files there with .tpl extension.  The docs have an example of using PROC TEMPLATE to delete a template from sasuser: https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/statcdc/14.2/statug/statug_odsgraph_sect052.htm

Comment: The output is just a line with a .v94 extension. No tpl...

Comment: I could be wrong about the template extension.  This paper also has SAS code for managing templates.  https://www.lexjansen.com/pharmasug/2010/SAS/SAS-TU-SAS02.pdf  Maybe read up on template management in similar papers at lexjansen.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution to my problem was the following:

Run this code to know the name of the template to delete:

```
proc template;
   list / store=sasuser.templat;
run;
```

And then run this one to delete the template:

```
proc template;
   delete base.freq.crosstabfreqs / store=sasuser.templat;
run;
```

Comment: Glad you found it! You should mark this as the accepted answer.